# "ReferenceError: <package> not defined" despite installing the package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I have a folder in which i have ran `npm install chevrotain` successfully. Running `npm -v chevrotain` gives `8.1.2` and I have `"chevrotain": "^10.1.2"` under my dependencies in my package.json but on running a simple js file in the same folder I get the error `ReferenceError: chevrotain is not defined`. The js file just has one line of code `const createToken = chevrotain.createToken`.

Any reasons why that could happen?

Comment: did you do an import?

Answer (score 1):

Having a package installed in your project doesn't create global variables in every module.

You need to explicitly import it using [`require`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) (for CommonJS modules) or [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (for ES modules).

The documentation for the module you are giving [provides an example](https://github.com/Chevrotain/chevrotain/blob/master/examples/tutorial/step1_lexing/step1_lexing.js):

> ```
> const chevrotain = require("chevrotain")
> ```